# Fresnel effect gone..well only partly shown.it changes when moving with camera

Tags: camera, transparency

As you can see, the right up corner shows fresnel while the other part of the model show white only...any idea? The effect changes along with camera movement. It is not the problem of Zoom in too much.
[image]

It was normal when i "Fresnel" the lettering, here is the result.
[image]
Now I want to do sprayed Acrylic on Pure Acrylic(Fresnel) board. The third picture shows that the effect is following the camera.
[image]

[image]

Comment: At first sight, this seems like [expected behavior](https://www.dorian-iten.com/fresnel/), although. visually, the effect is a little harsh, in the context.. probably depending on lighting, reflected environment, exposure.. can you give us a better idea of those other factors?

Comment: there you go..using the same fresnel node and same lighting too....i updated on  question... i am new to blender...sorry i cant explain properly

Comment: np, it's a tricky one, so many factors. Perhaps you should share a blend file which demonstrates the problem at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Link added......sorry late...just knew that i need to add the link

Comment: What real-world material are you trying to achieve, in that flat pane?

Comment: yes..An acrylic plane, Sprayed acrylic lettering on clear acrylic plane